# Serialize and Base64 convert and vice versa in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, serialization

I have functions which serialize and base64 convert objects and vice versa. It uses Newtonsoft to serialize and deserialize Objects. The code works but is there a way to do this without using Newtonsoft?

```
 Public Shared Function SerializeAndBase64(ObjectToSerialize As Object) As ReturnObject(Of String)
    Dim rtnObj As New ReturnObject(Of String)
    Try
        Dim SerializedObjectJson As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectToSerialize)
        Dim Base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SerializedObjectJson))
        rtnObj.Item = Base64String
    Catch ex As Exception
        rtnObj.ErrorID = ErrorHandler.handleError(ex)
        rtnObj.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        rtnObj.IsError = True
    End Try
    Return rtnObj
End Function

Public Shared Function DeserializeFromBase64(Of t)(Base64Json As String) As ReturnObject(Of t)
    Dim rtnObj As New ReturnObject(Of t)
    Try


        Dim SerializedObjectJson As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Base64Json))
        Dim DeserializedObject As t = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of t)(SerializedObjectJson)
        rtnObj.Item = DeserializedObject
    Catch ex As Exception
        rtnObj.ErrorID = ErrorHandler.handleError(ex)
        rtnObj.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        rtnObj.IsError = True
    End Try
    Return rtnObj
End Function
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes there are other serializers if that is what you are asking.  NET includes the BinaryFomratter; there is also Protobuf-net and MetSerializer

Comment: @Plutonix: +1 for [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance), also check [proto#](https://code.google.com/p/protosharp/).

Comment: If you need string serialization, check [DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I see that .Net includes serializes to convert object to XML but I couldn't find any inbuilt serializes to convert an object to string(not to save in a file). I dont't want to use any external libraries as far as possible. I want this to convert an object to string to save it in a cookie and later retrieve this cookie to get back the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can Serialize/Deserialize it yourself. You just have to come up with a way to save everything into a single string, or XML or even a byte array if you want. Your choice.

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Property MyValue As String

    Public Function Serialize() As String
        Return MyValue
    End Function

    Public Sub Deserialize(ByVal value As String)
        MyValue = value
    End Sub
End Class
```